# Python SL4A in other Language than English

Tags: android, python, sl4a, non-english, turkish

I am trying to write a small script which can speak in my own language.

`import sl4a
SpeakMe = sl4a.Android()
mesaj = SpeakMe.dialogGetInput('What would you want me to say ?')
SpeakMe.ttsSpeak(mesaj)`

when I run this code in my android it opens a dialog and let me enter a text so it can read it ; but i want it to read in my language cause it tries to read in English and it is very funny and wierd voicing.

is it possible to call tts to speak in any other language than English ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but you need go to mobile configuration choose language and input text, and text to speech, here choose the language you need your mobile speak. Finally write in you python script the following text:

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
#write Hello in chinese
str = "你好"
droid.ttsSpeak(str)
```